# Categorizing apps in Windows 7 start menu?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, start-menu, launcher

Is there any way to group related applications in Start Menu? Let's say I have a few Graphic software and a bunch of IDEs and I want to put them in a single item. Is it possible?

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic, so I removed that bit for you. Back to your query, why don't you create your own folders as required and drag-drop/copy-paste the shortcuts to group them?

Answer (score 2):

[Bins](http://www.1upindustries.com/bins/) is a Taskbar organizer which might work better than the Start Menu. Also, [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) will help you organize your Desktop. Fun stuff!